# Can the encrypt class in code igniter be used to send secure data in URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, base64, url-encoding

I try to send variable through URL. So I use this CI method

```
$this->encrypt->encode($variable)
```

And i decode it in the destination. but it doesn't return a correct value.
encoded value example :

> pWI+q72keVNJtpaZgJdxfwuKtqM2VrNMGhpnknsrf/3dadh0x+lU70h9hgSwFzTWQAEclSfoSZ2J3/UOuLVwgA==

I realize there are too much special characters here such as `+/=` . And to allow these characters in URI will be unwise.

If that so, is this function can't be implemented to secure data sent through URL?

Comment: AFAIK library name is `encrypt` and not `encryption` refer [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html)

Comment: @karanthakkar sorry, mistyping. I mean encrypt

Comment: you have `Mcrypt extension` ? which mode you use for encryption, also include which variable produce such OP

Comment: @karanthakkar i use the default one. If i use Mcrypt extension can it become shorter and less special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `encode` is Base64 encoded encrypted data. To transmit this you have to encode it in a URI-safe format.

On the [PHP base64 page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) those functions are proposed to

```
$base64 = $this->encrypt->encode($variable);
$urisafe = strtr($base64, '+/', '-_');
// or
$urisafe = strtr($base64, '+/=', '-_,');
```

Before `decode`ing you would have to reverse this:

```
$base64 = strtr($urisafe, '-_', '+/');
// or
$base64 = strtr($urisafe, '-_,', '+/=');
```

The first suggestion makes it compliant with the [RFC 4648 Table 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) for URL safe encodings.

[strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) replaces the offending characters with safe characters. In the above example during the encoding process `+` is replaced by `-` and `/` by `_`.

Answer (score 1):

I know what makes the encryption didn't return a correct value. It's because of its special characters.

```
pWI+q72keVNJtpaZgJdxfwuKtqM2VrNMGhpnknsrf/3dadh0x+lU70h9hgSwFzTWQAEclSfoSZ2J3/UOuLVwgA==
```

what's sent in this value is only `pWI+q72keVNJtpaZgJdxfwuKtqM2VrNMGhpnknsrf`, it happen because of `/` special characters.

So if we want to send this encoded value we have to make it uri safe. We can use `base64_encode()` after decoding and `base64_decode()` before decoding.
Like in this example :

To encode use

```
$id = '123';
$encrypted_id = $this->encrypt->encode($id);
$encrypted_id = base64_encode($encrypted_id);
//$url = 'www.trythis.com/site?id=' . $encrypted_id;
```

And to decode

```
$encrypted_id = $_GET['id'];
$encrypted_id = base64_decode($encrypted_id);
$decrypted_id = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_id);
```

Comment: Doing a second Base64 encoding step will remove some possible characters which makes it URL safe, but this also inflates your data another 30% that you need to send and receive more data and it will take longer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, for now i think it's the only solution for sending encrypted variable through URL. do you have better soultion?

Comment: I did provide an answer which should solve the problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. i just tried it. the result is amazingly shorter. what is strstr() functionality?

Comment: [It](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) replaces substrings and it's `strtr` not `strstr`.